# How can I ceate new array of elements based on a pattern found in another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that contains a bunch of random elements such as:

```
[{
    "id":332,
    "foo":6,
    "event":"ABC-CNEG Correlations Ed3.0 Update 9 (XY-AHZ)",
    "date":"2018-11-26T00:00:00.000Z",
 },
 {
    "id":324,
    "foo":1,
    "event":"ABC 3166-1_2013 No. VII-11",
    "date":"2018-06-30T00:00:00.000Z",
 },
 {
    "id":325,
    "foo":1,
    "event":"ABC 3166-2_2013 To. XII-32",
    "date":"2018-06-30T00:00:00.000Z",

 },
 {
    "id":326,
    "foo":2,
    "event":"ABC 3166-1_2016 No. VII-12",
    "date":"2018-06-30T00:00:00.000Z",
 },
 {
    "id":327,
    "foo":1,
    "event":"ABC 3166-2_2018 To. XII-31",
    "date":"2018-06-30T00:00:00.000Z",

 }]
```

What I need to do is "cherry pick" the above items and create a new array that contains ONLY the items that contain the following string: `3166-1`. So, the expected output would be:

```
[
 {
    "id":324,
    "foo":1,
    "event":"ABC 3166-1_2013 No. VII-11",
    "date":"2018-06-30T00:00:00.000Z",
 },
 {
    "id":326,
    "foo":2,
    "event":"ABC 3166-1_2016 No. VII-12",
    "date":"2018-06-30T00:00:00.000Z",
 }
]
```

My use case for this is so I can provide a filtered set of options for an HTML drop down select input.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can satisfy my use case and get a filtered set of items in a new array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `filter` function of the array and `includes` method of strings :

```js
let arr=[{
    "id":332,
    "foo":6,
    "event":"ABC-CNEG Correlations Ed3.0 Update 9 (XY-AHZ)",
    "date":"2018-11-26T00:00:00.000Z",
 },
 {
    "id":324,
    "foo":1,
    "event":"ABC 3166-1_2013 No. VII-11",
    "date":"2018-06-30T00:00:00.000Z",
 },
 {
    "id":325,
    "foo":1,
    "event":"ABC 3166-2_2013 To. XII-32",
    "date":"2018-06-30T00:00:00.000Z",

 },
 {
    "id":326,
    "foo":2,
    "event":"ABC 3166-1_2016 No. VII-12",
    "date":"2018-06-30T00:00:00.000Z",
 },
 {
    "id":327,
    "foo":1,
    "event":"ABC 3166-2_2018 To. XII-31",
    "date":"2018-06-30T00:00:00.000Z",

 }]
 
 
 let result=arr.filter(item=>item.event.includes('3166-1'))
 
 console.table(result)
```